# to find string that does not contain specific word

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that is going through range A and finding certain string that is having first 6 characters as numeric
the code is

```
Sub FindString()
   Dim A As Range, r As Range
   Set A = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:A"))
For Each r In A
    If IsNumeric(Left(r.Text, 6)) And InStr(1, r, "Totals:") Then

    MsgBox r.Value

    End If
Next r
End Sub
```

with this code it will return all the cells that is having first 6 characters numeric and having word Totals: in it

but I want to make change in this code that looks through string that is not having word Totals: in it

Comment: `If IsNumeric(Left(r.Text, 6)) And Not InStr(1, r, "Totals:") Then`

Comment: this does not work it gives string that is having word totals in it and strings that is not having word totals in it.

Comment: `cbool(InStr(1, r, "Totals:"))` = true if return > 0 else it is false ==>> use it as an `If ... Else ...`-condition will "auto-cbool" it

Comment: Do you just want the cells that do NOT have "Totals:" in it... regardless of the number at the beginning?

Comment: actually cells are having value like "200643    House of Horvath Inc"  and some cells are having first 6 characters numeric but they don't have company name in it instead they have totals:  so have to look for cells that  are having  first 6 characters numeric and does not contain word total in it.

Comment: oh sorry... you are right... `cbool( not number )` doesnt equal `not cbool( number)` ==>> `If IsNumeric(Left(r.Text, 6)) And Not cbool(InStr(1, r, "Totals:")) Then` or if the numeric part doesnt matter `If InStr(1, r, "Totals:") < 1 Then`

Comment: @DirkReichel Now I am directing this comment to you. In your first comment above, you have a clause that includes: `Not InStr()`. So I ask you, what is the value of `Not 7` ? Do you think it equals False?

Comment: just try it `Not number` = `-1 * (number + 1)` for your question 7 -> -8

Comment: so each positive number ( >0) will be true... however `not 0 = -1` whitch both is false, thats whyit doesnt work as apected

Comment: @DirkReichel I was pointing out the error in your logic. You cannot use the construct of `Not n` when 'n' is anything but zero and have it evaluate the to the equivalent of False. You must instead test for zero. I do not need the examples... I was trying to help you learn.

Comment: see my comment: `If InStr(1, r, "Totals:") < 1 Then` it is completely clear... logically (as bool) `instr() > 0` equals `instr()` ... however: i just wasnt using my brain properly and ended up with just putting a `Not` in front of it :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
If IsNumeric(Left(r, 6)) And 0 = InStr(r, "Totals:") Then
    MsgBox r
End If
```

Comment: If IsNumeric(Left(r.Text, 6)) And CBool(InStr(1, r, "Totals:")) = 0 Then   this works got me thanks excel hero

Comment: You had not answered my question by the time I posted. Updating answer now.

Comment: You do not need the CBool and you do not need the .Text.

Comment: @DirkReichel I was not directing my comment toward you. It was in response to OP's comment here on my answer.